# Start of String Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to match an occurrence of `1` that comes after either the beginning of the String or `a`.

I've tried `[\Aa]1`, but this gives me a PatternSyntaxException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a pattern like this:

```
(^|a)1
```

The `^` will match the begining of the string, while the `a` will match a literal Latin letter `a`. The `|` is called an alternation, and will match either the pattern on the left or the right, while parentheses restrict the scope of the alternation.

Now, this will include the `a` as part of the matched string. If you'd like to avoid this you can either use a lookbehind, like this:

```
(?<=^|a)1
```

This will match a `1`, but only if it is immediately preceeded by the beginning of the string or a Latin letter `a`.

Comment: \A is beginning of String. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html

Comment: @JoelA.Christophel You're absolutely right; I'm sorry. I just don't use that syntax at all, so I had forgotten it. I always use `^` just because it's easier for me to remember. I had assumed `[\Aa]` was an attempt to match `a` case insensitively. The reason why `\A` doesn't work inside a character class is that it's not actually a character, but a kind of zero-width assertion.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is what you mean but maybe you are looking for something like

```
(?<=\\A|a)1
```

or if you are not using `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag

```
(?<=^|a)1
```